# Laptop cannot connect internet after switch other router tru wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Currently I have 2 internet account, whereby each account hv own modem and router.
Account 1 (IP: 192.168.0.1 & Subnet:255.255.255.0) mostly work for network printer and CCTV NVR . Account 2 (IP: 192.168.1.1 & Subnet:255.255.255.0)for browsing internet.Network topo as shown in the diagram.

After disconnect from wifi#1 and connect to wifi#2, there is no problem to access internet. How ever if disconnect wifi#2 and reconnect wifi#1, I cant get tru my printer or internet.

What should I do to solve it?

[image]